# When not to use APNS in an IOS app?

Tags: ios, notifications, push, pusher

I am adding push notification services to my iOS app. I understand that I can either use APNS or another party like "Pusher". At this stage I only have an iOS model of the app. Why is it advantageous to use Pusher over APNS? Does it relate to the type of traffic,or the quantity of traffic ? Are notification alerts when the app is idle or in the background only possible with APNS ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why is it advantageous to use Pusher over APNS?

#### Speed

Pusher is better in most cases for in-application notifications, when the application is already open. It will be faster at delivering the messages (<250ms) than native Push Notifications since Pusher maintains a persistent connection to the server via a WebSocket connection.

#### In-Application Payload access

With Pusher you can also directly access the payload of the message within your application and the payload can be entirely custom. I'm not sure if an application can directly access the message payload in Push Notifications (I'd like clarification on this).

#### Ease of use

My personal opinion is that it's also much easier to trigger an event and receive an event with message payload using Pusher than it is to send a Push Notification.

Using Pusher you have code similar to the following on the server:

```
pusher.trigger('my-channel', 'my-event', {some:'data'});
```

On the client you have code similar to:

```
self.client = [PTPusher pusherWithKey:@"YOUR_APP_KEY" delegate:self];
[self.client connect];

PTPusherChannel *channel = [self.client subscribeToChannelNamed:@"my-channel"];

[channel bindToEventNamed:@"my-event" handleWithBlock:^(PTPusherEvent *channelEvent) {
  // channelEvent.data is a NSDictianary of the JSON object received
}];
```

> Does it relate to the type of traffic,or the quantity of traffic ?

#### Latency

As with the speed advantage above, if you are sending frequent data you will also get the benefit of Pusher's persistent WebSocket connection.

#### Payload size

In iOS 8 and above the maximum payload size of a notification is 2 kilobytes ([source](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH100-SW1)). The maximum payload of a Pusher message is 10 kilobytes.

> Are notification alerts when the app is idle or in the background only possible with APNS ?

Yes.

I'm not 100% sure if this will be possible with Pusher (investigation pending). So, this may be the scenario where native Push Notifications are better than Pusher.

Comment: Thanks Legetter. I found this useful.

Comment: @leggetter - did u investigate if Pusher can be used when app is in background?

Comment: @Sandbox no Pusher is not available in background mode.

Comment: "An application can directly access the message payload in Push Notifications" - yes it can. The payload itself is quite limited though.